# Encrypting data in oracle database

Tags: oracle, encryption, tde

What are the ways in which data can be encrypted? Say for example salary column, even the admin should not be able to see the encrypted columns if possible, data should be visible only through application to users who have access which is defined in the application, changes in application (adding new functionality to encrypt/decrypt at application level) would be a last resort and minimal.

So far I have thought of 2 ways any fresh ideas or pros and cons of the ones below would be much appreciated:
 1. Using Oracle TDE (transparent data encryption).
    - Con : Admin can possibly grant himself rights to see the data
 2. Creating a trigger to encrypt before insert and something along the lines of a pipeline to retrieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oracle Database Vault](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/database-vault/overview/index.html) is the only way to prevent a DBA from being able to access data stored in the database.  That is an extra cost product, however, and it requires you to have an additional set of security admins whose job it is to grant the DBAs whatever privileges they actually need.

Barring that, you'd be looking at solutions that encrypt and decrypt the data in the application outside the database.  That would involve making changes to the database structure (i.e. the `salary` column would be declared as a `raw` rather than a `number`).  And it involves application changes to call the encryption and decryption routines.  And that requires that you solve the key management problem which is generally where these sorts of solutions fail.  Storing the encryption key somewhere that the application can retrieve it but somewhere that no admin can access is generally non-trivial.  And then you need to ensure that the key is backed up and restored separately since the encrypted data in the database is useless without the key.

Most of the time, though, I'd tend to suggest that the right approach is to allow the DBA to see the data and audit the queries they run instead.  If you see that one particular DBA is running queries for fun rather than occasionally looking at bits of data in the course of doing her job, you can take action at that point.  Knowing that their queries are being audited is generally enough to keep the DBA from accessing data that she doesn't really need.